# Variable not carrying over from url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, get

I have the following code to use in a basic 'change email' script. Once I get it working I will worry more about validation but I can't, for the life of me, figure out why this is not working.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $u = $_GET['u'];
}

if (isset($_POST['e'])) { 
var_dump($_GET);
    $e = $_POST['e'];

    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows != 0) {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET email='$e' WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        echo "changed";
        exit();
    } else
        echo "Server issue";
        exit();
}
?>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function chEmail(){
    var e1 = _("email1").value;
    var e2 = _("email2").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if (e1 == "" || e2 == "") {
        status.innerHTML = "You need to complete both fields";
    } else if (e1 != e2) {
        status.innerHTML = "Emails don't match";
    } else {
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "changeEmail.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "changed"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("changeEmail").innerHTML = "Email successfully changed";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("e="+e1);
    }
}

</script>
<form id="changeEmail" name="changeEmail" onSubmit="return false">
<input type="text" id="email1" placeholder="Email"><br>
<input type="text" id="email2" placeholder="Confirm Email">
<span id="status"></span>
<button id="changeEmailBtn" onClick="chEmail()">Change</button>
</form>
```

The url is `http://mydomain.com/change_email.php?u=user`
The user is definitely in the database and I have double checked the table and field name.
The return every time is `Server issue`.

I have tried reversing the `num_rows` if statement (making it `==` instead of `!=` and switching the results) but get the same result.

I've tried moving the `$u = $_GET['u'];` to the second if statement. I've tried echoing `$u` in different places but it never shows the username.

I am still in the learning stage of PHP but I thought I could manage something this simple!

Let me know if you need me to show you my JavaScript but, as far as I can tell, that seems to be working with no problems.

Comment: Is your form being submitted as a POST request (`<form method="POST" ...>`)? If not, `$_POST['e']` will be empty, and your parameter can be accessed at `$_GET['e']` instead.

Comment: what error are you getting? AND why are you using both GET and POST to get the variables? do you actually have a field named e in your form + submitting the form as POST?

Comment: right off the bat I see you are missing a `{` on your else statement at the end other than that what issues are you having? oh and good eye @Yani why are you using both?

Comment: @KyleMassacre: It's not missing, it's just misindented.

Comment: The form is using post and sending the data through AJAX. The username is coming from the URL so I am `GET`ting the username and the form is `POST`ing the form data (which is just `e`.

Comment: @matt1985 please do var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @Yani I've not used that before. where do I put it?

Comment: right before if (isset($_POST['e'])) {

Comment: then post here what was the output, I'm guessing that you are not sumbitting the data correctly with Ajax

Comment: @Yani but if i use it after the `if (isset($_POST['e']))` I get `array(1) { ["e"]=> string(4) "matt" }`

Comment: @matt1985 before not after, just put it at the very top. It will show exactly what your ajax is submitting...

Comment: Then I get `array(0) { }` I've just tried the same with GET but my `$u` variable doesn't show

Comment: Then you are not posting the data correctly with Ajax. Please revise your question with the HTML + Javascript.

Comment: @Yani I have edited my post and included the whole `changeEmail.php` code

Comment: You aren't sending the `u` GET parameter in your AJAX POST request, simple

Comment: Why can't the PHP pick up the $u from the url?

Comment: @matt1985 Because the POST request (via AJAX) is only using the URL `changeEmail.php`. There is no `u` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't sending your `u` parameter in the AJAX request.

Try making these simple changes in your JS...

```
var url = _('changeEmail').action;

// snip

var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", url);
```

and in your form (assuming this is all within the same PHP file)...

```
<form action="changeEmail.php?u=<?= htmlspecialchars($u) ?>" ...
```

Now on to some more **meaty** issues

```
<?php
// make sure this is right at the top of your page

// this is to initialise $u so you can safely use it later on
$u = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : null;

if (isset($_POST['e'], $u)) {
    $e = $_POST['e'];

    require_once 'php_includes/db_conx.php';
    header('Content-type: text/plain');

    try {

        // couldn't see any reason for the SELECT statement so removed it

        // use prepared statements and parameter binding to avoid SQL injection.
        $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('UPDATE users SET email = ? WHERE username= ? LIMIT 1');
        if (!$stmt) {
            // some proper error handling goes a long way
            throw new Exception($db_conx->error, $db_conx->errno);
        }
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $e, $u);
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            throw new Exception($stmt->error, $stmt->errno);
        }
        if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
            echo 'changed';
        } else {
            // send proper error response codes
            http_response_code(404);
            echo 'zero records updated';
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // turn any exceptions into a usable response
        http_response_code(500);
        echo $e->getCode(), ': ', $e->getMessage();
    }
    exit;        
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htm>
    <!-- etc -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `ajaxObj` is an instance of `XMLHttpRequest` and defined in your included custom js script.

Try the following:

```
var username = "<?php isset($_GET['u']) ? echo $_GET['u'] : echo '';?>";
var ajax = ajaxObj("GET", "changeEmail.php?u=" + username + "&e=" + e1);
```

Then at the bottom simple put `ajax.send()` instead of `ajax.send("e="+e1);`

On your PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $u = $_GET['u'];
}

if (isset($_GET['e'])) { 
    $e = $_GET['e'];
...
```

}

Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess I declare your variable the same place I am declaring `e1` and `e2`? and the '?u=user1' is going to be different for each user...

Comment: that is correct, currently you are not sending any user name at all.

Comment: The page that contains the link to this page is sending the username. the link is`<a href='http://mydomain.com/changeEmail.php?u=<?php echo $u; ?>'>click here</a>

Comment: @matt1985 revised my answer to show you how to get it into javascript

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the line `var username = <?php isset($_GET['u']) ? echo $_GET['u'] : echo '';?>;`

Comment: I'm still getting a syntax error... Do I have to `</script>` to use `<?php ?>` in js?

Comment: no you don't but the javascript has to be within the <script></script> tags that you already have.

Comment: Then I don't know why I'm getting a syntax error? It doesn't like anything on the line after `var username = "<?php isset($_GET['u'])`

Comment: man, you need to learn to debug you application. Don't worry about why the syntax is happening now, just put any existing user name there that you know would be found in the DB (var username = 'existing_username') and continue to see if your rest of the app works.

Comment: @Yari Thanks for your patience :) All your changes seem to do is make the form duplicate itself? http://i59.tinypic.com/axb3n7.jpg

Comment: why would the form duplicate itself? I think you may have not been clear in your question and I'm not sure how I can help you any further except for taking a flight there and writing it myself...sorry man you need to first learn how to post a form using ajax or jQuery $.ajax and then how to read the variables. I think that my answer explained it well but I may have misunderstood your original question...

Comment: I don't know... This is driving me crazy! I'll do some more reading up  and will scrap and rebuild the entire page. Thank you again for your patience and help.

Comment: OK, last thing that I just thought of - try to move the PHP into its own file such as script.php and then replace your javascript to var ajax = ajaxObj("GET", "script.php?u=" + username + "&e=" + e1);

Comment: If all your PHP, HTMl and Javascript are in 1 file, and you are posting with Ajax to the SAME file - it will never work.